# How to texture paint across all objects that share the same material/image?

Tags: materials, texture-painting

This is a greybox project, so we shouldn't take in account detail or sustainability. Just something that will "work".

I have several objects that share one UV map and one material. I used Smart UV project for all of them so that it would pack them in the same space. I made a new image and applied it to the material.
I can texture paint each object just fine. However, I need to paint across all of them at the same time, in the 3D viewport (not the image editor). As it is, I need to select each object, then go to Texture paint and I can see my previous strokes, but I need to see them all at the same time (I'm making relationship lines etc). How to do this?
Also, my texture doesn't appear at all in material mode, although I have connected the texture to the diffuse channel.
[image]

Comment: Hi mate, could You send the .blend here? Its somehow important if You want to draw on each object serapately or **exact same shape on some parts of multiple objects in the same time** - cause in this case, You could paint on one and affect all others using overlapping islands. I need a better explanation to help (if possible) and cause of that I need your scene.

Comment: Added my blend. I want different textures on everything (I want to write what is each block, and how it relates to each other).

Comment: @JanMatys did you have any luck with my blend?

Answer (score 1):

If they already share all the same UV space, then temporarily you could then join them together until the paint stage is done.

Comment: I'm kinda scared to do so. I have lost work previously with the join method, even though I saved everything externally.

Comment: @mechanicarts if you duplicate the objects and join the duplicates your originals will remain intact.